# Coordinates system changed in Fabric.js 1.3.12?

Tags: fabricjs

**TL; DR**: why is the location of the image different?

There seems to be some difference in the coordinate system between 1.3.0 and 1.3.12. Here are the HTML file `test.html`, working with the newly cloned and built fabric.js by myself ():

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./fabric.js/dist/all.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript file `test.js`:

```
$(function(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  fabric.Image.fromURL('test.png', function(img) {
    var group = new fabric.Group([img],
    {
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false,
      selectable: true,
      evented: true,
    })
    canvas.add(group);
  });
});
```

The web page looks like

[image]

But if I change fabric.js to the version on the CDN, which is 1.3.0:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.3.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

The web page will look like

[image]

The second case makes more sense for me. It puts the center of the image to `(0,0)`. But in the first case it seems to put the image center to `(image_width, image_height)`. So is this a bug? Or a feature of coordinate system for groups?

**UPDATE**: if simply using

```
$(function(){
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  canvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  canvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  fabric.Image.fromURL('test.png', function(img) {
    canvas.add(img);
  });
});
```

, the top left corner of the image will be attached to `(0,0)`.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: OK, I need to manually set `{left: 0, top:0}` for the group. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is that `originX`/`originY` default values were changed to "left"/"top" from "center"/"center".

This was a very confusing behavior to almost anyone starting with Fabric and we finally got rid of it. You can see this breaking change in a changelog (between unreleased edge/dev version and latest stable 1.3.0)

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

`originX`/`originY` represent what left/top values of an object are relative to. All objects' left/top used to be relative to their centers; now we're using more common system of left/top corner.